# What is the best way to remove 'a', 'an' and 'the' from the start of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, character

I'm creating a way to filter a set of blog posts by the first letter of the title. The only trouble is that I, of course, want to remove 'A ', 'An ' and 'The ' from the beginning of the titles before I select them by letter. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
$title = strtolower( $_POST['post_title'] );
$title = substr($title, 0, 2) == 'a ' ? substr($title, 2) : $title;
$title = substr($title, 0, 3) == 'an ' ? substr($title, 3) : $title;
$title = substr($title, 0, 4) == 'the ' ? substr($title, 4) : $title;
```

That works fine, but it seems pretty clunky. Is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this kind of thing pretty robustly with `str_replace`:

```
$title = "A is what this title starts with";
$splitTitle = explode(" ", $title);
$blacklist = array("an","a","the");
$splitTitle[0] = str_replace($blacklist,"",strtolower($splitTitle[0]));
$revisedTitle = implode(" ", $splitTitle);
echo $revisedTitle
```

This will replace only the string found before the first space. It splits the string with `explode`, removes the first fragment if it contains a member of `$blacklist` using `str_replace`, then rejoins the string with `implode`.

Result:

> is what this title starts with

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
preg_replace('/^((the|an|a)\s)/i','',$title);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $vowels = array("a", "an", "the");
 $title= str_replace($vowels, "", $title);
```

for more info :- https://www.php.net/str_replace

Comment: This wouldn't work for a title beginning with `An`, it will replace the `a` and leave `n', you need to swap the order of "a" and "an"